# Visual Studio MFC Radio Button error with variable

Tags: mfc

I am a Visual Studio MFC newbie, and have been a bit perplexed by a problem over the last couple of days.  When I create a radio button and assign it variable, I get a "Debug Assertion Failed".  How should I make the radio button a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the first radio button in a sequence of radio buttons is of style `WS_GROUP`. It is a style you can set in the dialog editor by selecting the first radio button and setting its style to Group.

You want to use an `int` as the type to receive/set and only use `DDX_Radio()` on the first radio button on the group. It will return 0 if first radio selected, 1 if second, 2 if third, etc... Make sure the value you use, a member variable is initially set to 0 or another valid value.